# A bug that is not present in debug mode, but just when i run the project

Tags: java, oop, comparable, treeset

i'm working on a school project, we're building an Electronic Grade book, it's just a project to learn better OOP and UML nothing of real. And we got blocked in a strange bug we worked for a lot of time trying to solve it, but we couldn't find a solution for it. The function that read the students names, date, class, and so on. Has a strange bug when we debug it, it read all the info and save to the class array without any problem but when we run it, some students are not added to the class although the output seems to be non-deterministic. I did find a way to overcome this bug by adding a thread sleep of 1 ms in the function and it worked. But we have no idea why and what's the problem, it just makes no sense. We worked for like 10 hours searching for a reason and a real solution.

This is the function:

```
/**
     * Import the studend list from a text file and load them into an array
     * @param nomeFile file name of the studend 
     * @param classi array name of all the classes 
     * @param nclassi number of classes 
     * @return number of student imported 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException, IOException problemi con la lettura del file
     *         IndexOutOfBoundsException problemi di inserimento dell'alunno nella classe specificata
     *         Exception problemi con la data di nasciita dello studente
     */
    public static int importaIscrizioniAlunni(String nomeFile, Classe[] classi, int nclassi) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException,IndexOutOfBoundsException,Exception {
        
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String riga = "";  
        int iscrizioni=0;

        // Carico le iscrizioni effettuate dagli alunni dal file
        try 
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nomeFile)); 

            //PROBLEM STARTS
            while ((riga = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String[] campi = riga.split(",");
                // campi[1] => cognome
                // campi[2] => nome
                // campi[3] => sesso
                // data nascita: campi[4] => giorno campi[5] => mese campi[6] => anno
                // campi[7] => classe campi[8] => sezione 
                Studente nuovo = new Studente(campi[0], campi[1], campi[2], campi[3].charAt(0),  Integer.valueOf(campi[4]), Integer.valueOf(campi[5]), Integer.valueOf(campi[6]));

                Classe classe_scelta = new Classe(Integer.parseInt(campi[7]), campi[8].charAt(0), null);
                
                //print the new student and new class using toString just for debug purposes
                System.out.println("input: " + nuovo .toString()+ " " + classe_scelta.toString());
                for(int i = 0; i < nclassi; i++)
                {
                    //trova la classe
                    if(classi[i].equals(classe_scelta))
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            classi[i].aggiungi(nuovo);
                            //print the new student and new class just for debug purposes
                            System.out.println("Iscrizione effettuata: " + nuovo.getCognome() + " " + nuovo.getNome() + " " + classi[i].getSezione() + " " + classi[i].getPercorso().getannoCorso() + "\n\n\n");
                            break;
                        } 
                        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) 
                        {
                            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
                        }
                    }
                }
                iscrizioni++;
                //Thread.sleep(1); Solve the bug but it's not the best solution we couldn't find what is causing the bug
                
                //print the class using toString just for debug purposes
                for(int i = 0; i < nclassi; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(classi[i]);
                }
            }
            //PROBLEM ENDS
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException("Errore di accesso al file");
    } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Errore generico durante importazione alunni (probabile data non valida nel file)");
    }finally {
            if (br != null) {
        try {
                    br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new IOException("Errore durante chiusura del file");  
                }
            } 
        }
        return iscrizioni;
    }
```

I'm sorry if the variables are in Italian but due to the fact of being a team school project, we had to adapt for everyone, as you can see this method read the student find his class and add the student to it.

The "aggiungi" method which means add:

```
    public void aggiungi(Studente nuovo) throws IllegalArgumentException 
    { 
        if (this.numeroStudenti + 1 <= MAX_STUDENTI)
        {
            this.elenco.add(nuovo);
            nuovo.classe = this;
            nuovo.assegnaMatricola();
            numeroStudenti++;
        }
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

We add the student to the internal container which is a Set, and we then set the class of the student to be this one, then we assign  the student ID and finally we increase the student number.

Any help is very appreciated, we're getting mad because the code is working when we debug it, and if you need more information on the code or even the full repository just ask for it. Thanks in advice.

We tried do debug it several time and it works, we tried to use several output for debugging purpose, we did try the single add function, we checked if the problem was created by reading the file and it doesn't seems to be, we also saw that if we put the break point while debugging after the method call the  problem still persist and everything is working as it should.

This is an example of the output in run mode:

This is the text file of the students:

```
RSSMRA00R05A519L,Rossi,Mario,m,10,5,2000,3,A
VRDLGU99A01E423D,Verdi,Luigi,m,1,1,1999,3,A
BNCPLA00S63D848E,Bianchi,Paola,f,23,11,2000,3,A
CRLNRE99D45E458M,Neri,Carlo,m,5,4,1999,4,A
GLIRTT99D45D852Z,Rossetto,Giulia,f,2,2,1998,4,A
RSORSO99D45D852K,Rosa,Rosa,f,25,4,1998,4,A
GLLDRA99E04A182Y,Gialli,Dario,m,4,5,1999,4,A
VLIVLI98C43A182B,Viola,Viola,f,3,3,1998,4,B
RSSMRC98M14A182A,Rossi,Marco,m,14,8,1998,4,B
```

And this is the output:

```
input: Matricola: 0, Rossi, Mario Classe 3^A
Registration completed: Rossi Mario A 3

classes:
Classe 3^A
1: Matricola: 1, Rossi, Mario

Classe 4^A

Classe 4^B



input: Matricola: 0, Verdi, Luigi Classe 3^A
Registration completed: Verdi Luigi A 3

classes:
Classe 3^A
1: Matricola: 1, Rossi, Mario
2: Matricola: 2, Verdi, Luigi

Classe 4^A

Classe 4^B


input: Matricola: 0, Bianchi, Paola Classe 3^A
Registration completed: Bianchi Paola A 3

classes:
Classe 3^A
1: Matricola: 1, Rossi, Mario
2: Matricola: 2, Verdi, Luigi

Classe 4^A

Classe 4^B


input: Matricola: 0, Neri, Carlo Classe 4^A
Registration completed: Neri Carlo A 4

classes:
Classe 3^A
1: Matricola: 1, Rossi, Mario
2: Matricola: 2, Verdi, Luigi

Classe 4^A
1: Matricola: 4, Neri, Carlo

Classe 4^B


input: Matricola: 0, Rossetto, Giulia Classe 4^A
Registration completed: Rossetto Giulia A 4

classes:
Classe 3^A
1: Matricola: 1, Rossi, Mario
2: Matricola: 2, Verdi, Luigi

Classe 4^A
1: Matricola: 4, Neri, Carlo

Classe 4^B


input: Matricola: 0, Rosa, Rosa Classe 4^A
Registration completed: Rosa Rosa A 4

classes:
Classe 3^A
1: Matricola: 1, Rossi, Mario
2: Matricola: 2, Verdi, Luigi

Classe 4^A
1: Matricola: 4, Neri, Carlo

Classe 4^B

input: Matricola: 0, Gialli, Dario Classe 4^A
Registration completed: Gialli Dario A 4

classes:
Classe 3^A
1: Matricola: 1, Rossi, Mario
2: Matricola: 2, Verdi, Luigi

Classe 4^A
1: Matricola: 4, Neri, Carlo
2: Matricola: 7, Gialli, Dario

Classe 4^B


input: Matricola: 0, Viola, Viola Classe 4^B
Registration completed: Viola Viola B 4

classes:
Classe 3^A
1: Matricola: 1, Rossi, Mario
2: Matricola: 2, Verdi, Luigi

Classe 4^A
1: Matricola: 4, Neri, Carlo
2: Matricola: 7, Gialli, Dario

Classe 4^B
1: Matricola: 8, Viola, Viola


input: Matricola: 0, Rossi, Marco Classe 4^B
Registration completed: Rossi Marco B 4

classes:
Classe 3^A
1: Matricola: 1, Rossi, Mario
2: Matricola: 2, Verdi, Luigi

Classe 4^A
1: Matricola: 4, Neri, Carlo
2: Matricola: 7, Gialli, Dario

Classe 4^B
1: Matricola: 8, Viola, Viola
```

Just a remainder the output is non-deterministic as far as i know so another run will give a different output also some time after a lot of try it will give a right answer. As you can see not all students are being registered.

Comment: What platform are you on? What Java version are you using? Are you running your code from an IDE? If so, which one? What is the encoding of the text file you are reading? Are you creating new `Thread`s anywhere in your code?

Comment: im on linux, java java 18 2022-03-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18+36-2087)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18+36-2087, mixed mode, sharing)
on vs code, and the file is text/csv; charset=us-ascii according to the linux file command, no we did't create any thread.

Comment: I just found this question by accident, looking for something else. I guess if I would see the complete code, I could find out what is wrong within three minutes. So if you can publish the project on GitHub and notify me with a comment, tomorrow morning I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the interest, i just made the repository public here the link: https://github.com/MRn0b0dy0/Registro-eletronico.git. Thank you.

Comment: After you presented the MCVE on GitHub, this initially unclear question became a wonderful debugging exercise and an example of what kind of things go wrong when not correctly implementing `compareTo` and `equals`. Therefore, I upvoted it. Please do not delete it like so many new users do after they received an answer. There is no reason to be shy or embarrassed about this. A `compareTo` bug can happen to the best of us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without it, it would have been impossible to find out what was wrong, because the problems are in parts of the code you did not show.

The problem starts with the fact that the user base class `Utente extends GregorianCalendar`. A user ***is not*** a calendar. Maybe a user ***has*** or ***uses*** one or more calendars. If your class is about OOP principles, you may want to study the differences between [generalisation (inheritance) vs. composition vs. aggregation vs. association](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-aggregation-vs-composition/).

The rather technical problem with `Utente` extending `GregorianCalendar` is that its parent class `Calendar` already implements `Comparable<Calendar>`. So if you want to override `compareTo`, you cannot just override `compareTo(Object)` like you tried (but commented out), or even `compareTo(Studente)` in order to achieve sorting in a `TreeSet`, but you need to override `compareTo(Calendar)`. The other two variants will never be called.

Background: Due to [type erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure), You cannot implement the same interface twice for different generic types, i.e. something like `Studente extends Utente implements Comparable<Studente>` will yield a compile error `"java.lang.Comparable cannot be inherited with different arguments: <scuola.Studente> and <java.util.Calendar>"`.

The consequence of the above is that, the way your code looks now on GitHub, your `TreeSet<Studente>` will be sorted as a set of `Calendar` objects. But `Utente` does not initialise the parent calendar instance by calling `super(...)` in its own constructors, i.e. the calendar will be uninitialised, because only its default constructor with no arguments will be called. But that one is inherited by `Object` and not overridden by any calendar or user class, i.e. `Calendar.compareTo`, when noticing that no time is set for itself, will simply always use `System.currentTimeMillis()`. The results are hard to predict and seem non-deterministic, even though of course they are perfectly deterministic, but dependent on when `compareTo` is called for which `Studente` object, and which ones are on the left and right hand sides of the comparison.

Therefore, because `Calendar.compareTo(Calendar)` is inadequate for class `Studente`, the `TreeSet` will have inconsistent sorting and e.g. A < B and B < C does not reliably mean A < C. It could even be that you get A < B one time and B < A at the same time. Your `TreeSet`, if you simply print its size or print its `toString()` value to the console, will show the correct size and the correct set of `Studente` elements. But when iterating over it like you do in the `Classe.toString()` method, you will see strange results due to the bogus ordering, because it upsets the set iterator. By the way, I would recommend a `toString` method printing only a simple string without line breaks. If you want to print something with multiple lines, you should do so in a utility method.

So you have several choices:

1. Implement `compareTo(Calendar)` in `Studente` (maybe also in `Utente`, if you need it there). But then you need to make sure that it also does something meaningful for other `Calendar` instances passed in or at least throws meaningful exceptions if something other than a `Student` is passed in. But like I said, a student or user is not a calendar, so this feels awfully wrong.
2. Remove `extends GregorianCalendar` from `Utente` and let `Studente implements Comparable<Studente>` instead. Then implement a `compareTo(Studente)` method which is consistent with `equals(Object)`. Because your `equals` method compares first by ID (`matricola`), then by last name (`cognome`) and first name (`nome`), you should do the same in `compareTo` and not use some other criterion like `mediaVoti()` there. If you want to sort by average votes (whatever that means in your context), you can still do so later using `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` or so, using a custom comparator.
3. Do not implement `Comparable` at all, use a normal, unsorted set and sort students on demand using `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`.

I am showing you no. 2, so you can learn something about `Comparable` and `compareTo`:

```java
public class Utente /*extends GregorianCalendar*/ {
    // ...
}
```

```java
public class Studente extends Utente implements Comparable<Studente> {
    // ...
    /**
     * Confronta per matricola, cognome, nome
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Studente altroStudente) {
        if (this.equals(altroStudente))
            return 0;
        int result = Integer.compare(matricola, altroStudente.matricola);
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        result = cognome.compareTo(altroStudente.cognome);
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        return nome.compareTo(altroStudente.nome);
    }
    // ...
}
```

This solution also is not perfect, because it will throw exceptions if first or last names are `null`. But I guess for your simple solution this is acceptable.

There are many other smaller and bigger problems in your application, but I know you are all just starting, and I think all in all you have achieved a lot together as a group.  Just some small things:

- `Classe.equals(Object)` contains a bug: `if (altro == this) return false;` should be `if (altro == this) return true;`.
- `PercorsoDidattico.equals(Object)` also contains a problem: When comparing strings, you should use `equals`, never `==`, i.e. instead of `an.indirizzo == this.indirizzo` you ought to use `an.indirizzo.equals(this.indirizzo)`.

I could write more, but the answer is long already.

After fixing the two `equals` methods and implementing the `Comparable<Studente>` interface correctly, your program prints:

```
...
input: Matricola: 0, Rossi, Marco Classe 4^B

Iscrizione effettuata: Rossi Marco B 4

Classe 3^A
1: Matricola: 0, Bianchi, Paola
2: Matricola: 0, Rossi, Mario
3: Matricola: 0, Verdi, Luigi

Classe 4^A
1: Matricola: 0, Gialli, Dario
2: Matricola: 0, Neri, Carlo
3: Matricola: 0, Rosa, Rosa
4: Matricola: 0, Rossetto, Giulia

Classe 4^B
1: Matricola: 0, Rossi, Marco
2: Matricola: 0, Viola, Viola
```

As you can see, the new `compareTo(Studente)` method leads to each class being sorted by student last name, then first name, because `matricola` is still unused in your program.

---

**Update:** By the way, the explanation for why it worked correctly in the debugger or with an additional `Thread.sleep()` is probably related to `Calendar.compareTo` using different timestamps, which accidentally led to at least the iterator finding all elements in the tree-set. Depending on your code, that would still have failed in other situations, you were just lucky there.

Comment: Thank you, i'm sorry i don't know how i missed that while reviewing the whole project, i didn't make that class but i should have noticed the error. i will correct the project. Thank you for your kindness and for have understated that this is our first OOP project as we are still high school students. Have a nice day.

Comment: The problem was that `Classe.toString` printed misleading information, because that method itself was affected by the bug. That led your team to not debugging properly, relying on the `toString` output, which is understandable. When stepping throuhg the application in a debugger or adding additional output about size and content of `Classe` instances, you quickly notice the discrepancies. Implementing `equals` and `compareTo` correctly in order not to mess up iterators, is not as trivial as it might seem.

Comment: Please note my update, explaining why it seemed to work for you with extra delays in the program.